# When should I make new object in constructor and What is the value of new object

Tags: apex, soql, controller

I want to know when should I create new object in the constructor, And the same thing with List ..

And What is the value of Object x, before the new statement and after new statement.

when I write

```
public account Account {set; get;} // what is the value of account ?
```

and in constructor

```
account = new Account(); // what is the value now ?
```

because I'm trying to check `if (account != null)` after `SELECT statement` but I want to understand the logic before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer:

account is `null` **until you assign a value to it**.  In your case after `select statement`

### Extended answer:

From my understanding, you should understand the execution order of a controller (or other classes in apex)

When an execution context is created for a controller:

1. The controller class is initiated on memory. This means that all `static` attributed are initiated.
2. the controller instance is initiated on memory. This means that the instance is created on memory assigning the default value to each attribute. E.g:  `public boolean myFlag = false;`  That is attribute is `null` until this step.
3. The controller *constructor* is executed. Now, you can assign any value to yours attributes.
4. The VF page (or other source) try to access to a controller attribute by `{!myFlag}` the method `get` is executed. In the same way if the VF try to set a default value to any attribute the `set` method is call.

Comment: Ok, but I have account Object with default salary = 1000, and I have `<apex:inputField value="{!account.salary}" />`. before I create new object the value is 1000, but when i write new statement in constructor, the field is empty !

Comment: Are you using the standarController Account and creating an extension? if yes, account as already a value set by the standard controller.

Comment: No, it's only a custom controller without standard

Comment: So, the only way that account.salary is taken 1000 is that you are assigning some account before call the new statement

Answer (score 1):

```
public account Account {set; get;} // It will be initialized with null value.


account = new Account(); // Here you are crating a new Account object and assigning its reference to account object.
```

Comment: dependent on your explanation, if I check account value after new statement, if(account == null) the result is true or false ?

Answer (score 1):

public account Account {set; get;} - this is null

account = new Account(); - and this is new account instance with no values